# OpenFDA Medical Device 510(k) other information than summary/statement

Tags: api, openfda, government

Is it possible to identify all 510k records of medical devices were a `FDA review` or `clinical trials` is available (e.g. https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfpmn/pmn.cfm?ID=K151502) using either the API, the dataset (https://open.fda.gov/apis/device/510k/download/) or any other database?

Records with a summary/statement can easily be identified by `statement_or_summary` in the provided dataset.

**Update:**

Just saw that the online search mask (https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfPMN/pmn.cfm) offers a box to filter results with clinical trials. Is this information also available with the api or the /device/510k data file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Jack with the openFDA team. To my knowledge none of the fields in the openFDA 510k API flag the record as a clinical trial. There are no plans to add this at present.

Thank you,
Jack Finch

Comment: Thank you for your help. I assume the same applies to FDA reviews?